# "file may be locked by F# Interactive process" when opening FsCheck

Tags: visual-studio-code, f#, f#-interactive, fscheck

When i try to open FsCheck through 
#r "FsCheck"
open FsCheck
commands, in a .fsx file, i get this error.

Tried googling but noone of the answers i found solved my problem.

> #r "FsCheck"
>   - open FsCheck;;

--> Referenced '/*/FsCheck.dll' (file may be locked by F# Interactive process)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not an error. Fsi is just warning you that it is locking the file, so you won't be able to change it. For example, if this dll was the output of a project that you are working on, then your next compilation would fail to overwrite it, and you would have to restart fsi to be able to compile again.